# Alfresco or confluence

Tags: cms, alfresco

I am looking for document management tools at enterprise level. And am focused between two alfresco and confluence. Confluence is little expensive compare to licensing of each.

Must-Have features:

1. Workflow
2. Document management / uploads
3. Data center (High availability support, Optimized for LDAP)
4. User role and group based accessibility
5. Highly customization (skin/ email template/notification)
6. Unlimited users to view/comment (anonymous)
7. Calendars
8. Discussion boards (With more customized templates)
9. Project blogs

Any help/thoughts in comparison of both will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) Are you fixed on those two, or open to other suggestions as well?

Comment: You could just install Alfresco community and give that a try since it has all that stuff.